# Promote all builds to master on Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket-server

I'm using Jenkins for CI on my project. Right now, I have a "Dev" build, which is triggered by Stash (git server) any time a commit is made to any branch.

I'm trying to incorporate my release workflow as well. Here's the plan:

- Dev job uses the Promoted Builds plugin to promote all builds to `master`
- Release job is triggered by the promotion of Dev

However, I can't seem to figure out how to promote a build based on its branch. I've tried the "promote immediately based on build parameters" and specified the `GIT_BRANCH` to be `origin/master`. When I run the build, I `echo %GIT_BRANCH%` and it prints `origin/master` when it's supposed to.

I also tried adding a string parameter `BRANCH` to the build and `set BRANCH=%GIT_BRANCH%` in my build script in case it actually needs to be a parameter rather than just an environment variable.

Still stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Added a String build parameter called `IS_RELEASE_CANDIDATE` with a default value of `0`. I'm using "Promote immediately once the build is complete based on build parameters" with the condition that `IS_RELEASE_CANDIDATE` is `1`.

In my build steps, I've added a Conditional step using the [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) to be run when the strings `$GIT_BRANCH` and `stash/master` match.

If they match, I use the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to set `IS_RELEASE_CANDIDATE=1`.

Comment: I tried setting this up with no luck - are you still using this configuration?

Comment: As far as I know, it's still working, but this was at my old job so I no longer have access to the build server.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by using the `Custom Groovy Script` option, which is provided a `build` object from which you can access environment variables.  This script will only allow promotions on builds that match the `origin/master` branch.

[image: Screenshot of configuration]